# Error converting (sql) data type varchar to float... but nothing is float

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure in which none of the source, nor any of the target, nor any of the columns involved in joining stuff into the source, columns have datatype float. But when I try and run it, I'm getting

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

I've gone through every column referenced in the source and commented out to try and figure out which thing it's trying to convert, but it seems to always give the same message.

My columns are all `varchar(255)` or `int`, so far as I can tell.

```
with temp_mart as (
    select 
    ca.YearMonth as Date,
    s.ID as SurveyID,
    t.TeamName as Team,
    q.MetricID,
--  cast(C.City as varchar(255)) as City,
    r.Role,
    QR.QuestionID,
    QR.ID as QuestionResponseID,
    QR.Rating,
    QR.OpenResponse,
    QT.ID as QuestionTypeID
from QuestionResponses QR
join lkup.Questions Q on Q.QuestionID=QR.QuestionID
join lkup.Teams T on t.id=Q.TeamID
join lkup.Surveys S on s.id=q.SurveyID
join lkup.Calendar ca on ca.id=s.ValidFromID
join Responses RE on RE.Qualtrics_ID=QR.Qualtrics_ID
join lkup.Roles R on r.id=re.roleID
join lkup.Cities C on c.id=re.cityID
join lkup.QuestionType QT on QT.ID=Q.QuestionTypeID
where (select count(cityid) from responses) > 3
)
merge DataMart as target
using temp_mart as source
on (source.QuestionResponseID = target.QuestionResponseID)
when matched then update 
set 
    target.Rating=source.Rating,
    target.OpenResponse=source.OpenResponse
when not matched by target
    then insert (
            Date, 
            SurveyID, 
            Team,
            MetricID,
            -- City
            Role, 
            QuestionID, 
            QuestionResponseID,
            Rating,
            OpenResponse,
            QuestionTypeID)
        values (
            source.Date, 
            source.SurveyID, 
            source.Team, 
            source.MetricID, 
            --source.City, 
            source.Role, 
            source.QuestionID, 
            source.QuestionResponseID, 
            source.Rating, 
            source.OpenResponse,
            source.QuestionTypeID)
```

Comment: Are any of your sources views? The view's source table could be the cause of the error.

Comment: They're all tables..